# How to remap ; (semicolon) in AutoHotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

My goal is to remap ; (semicolon) to Control + k. However that doesn't work since ; starts a comment instead of being recognized as a key.

This is my code:

```
^k::;
```

I do have a workaround that kind of works but it is causing a mess with the curly braces:

```
{ ;Semicolon
    ^k::
    send, {; down}
    send, {; up}
    return  
}
```

The curly braces after "down" and after "up" are not recognized as brackets but as part of the comment.

Comment: The `}` after the down and up **are** recognized. From the help doc, "the semicolon must have at least one space or tab to its left." Also, this works for me, `^k::Send , {;}`.

Comment: The following works too, but again it's creating a mess with folding the code: 
``` 
^k:: sendevent, {`;} return 
``` 
All of the brackets are recognized but not entirely because the folding doesn't work...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found the answer myself!

```
^k::
Send, {Text};
return
```

Everything that comes after {Text} will be interpreted as text only!

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
`;::?
```

(? being used as wildcard)

did a quick google search and found this: https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/33122-how-to-remap-semicolon-key/  Not sure if this is what you are looking for though.

Comment: This may also be a decrepit solution, since this forum thread was from over a decade ago

Comment: Are you trying to map semicolon to execute control+k or control+k to semicolon?

If you are trying to do the latter, this should work:   

^k::`;

Comment: reading up on escapeChars might be useful,
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs_1.0/commands/_EscapeChar.htm

Comment: Hey Calisto,
First of all thanks for your efforts, unfortunately none of it works ;(

Comment: @IoCalisto, decrepit or deprecated? 